# Calling a prototype method while preserving state

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble making a recursive call in this prototype method.  The console prints:

```
count 1 (index):30
Uncaught ReferenceError: count is not defined
```

Instead, I need it to print:

```
count 1 (index):30
count 2 (index):30
```

...

```
var MyClass, mc;

MyClass = (function() {
  function MyClass() {
    this.count = 1;
  }

  MyClass.prototype.method = function() {
    console.log("count", this.count);
    this.count++;
    if (count === 2) {
      method();
    }
  };

  return MyClass;

})();

mc = new MyClass();

mc.method();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/audfmotf/

Comment: More on prototype and constructor functions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a couple of `this` inside `method`.

```
MyClass.prototype.method = function() {
  console.log("count", this.count);
  this.count++;
  if (this.count === 2) {
    this.method();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`count` is not the same as `this.count`. Your condition checks for an undefined variable, instead of:

```
if (this.count === 2) {
      this.method();
    }
```